# GWT plugin for SBT / Using the Maven Plugin

Tags: maven-2, gwt, sbt

Does anyone know of a GWT plugin for SBT? I can't seem to find one anywhere.

If there isn't one, does anyone know how to use maven plugins from SBT for some tasks? I know this is possible, but can't figure out how. Can I just fit in the maven GWT plugin and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One exists here:

https://github.com/thunderklaus/sbt-gwt-plugin

and my fork of it which adds the ability to run your project in the devmode shell:

https://github.com/samskivert/sbt-gwt-plugin